# Why does ServiceStack's DefaultRedirectPath redirects with HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Tags: servicestack

Why does ServiceStack's v4 **DefaultRedirectPath** redirects with **HTTP** instead of **HTTPS** despite I have reconfigured it as shown below:

```
    appHost.Config.UseHttpsLinks = true;
    appHost.Config.DefaultRedirectPath = "/swagger-ui/";
```

[image]